# PHP External Oauth : how to displaying a waiting message while waiting for callback (not using AJAX)

Tags: php, callback, popup

We allow external OAuth using PHP APIs to several social networks. When the user choose external authentication, a new window (popup) is opened, where the application asks authorization. Then, still in the popup, the user is redirected using the callback url given to the external application. The callback script performs various tasks (login, checks, synchronization,...) that may requires some time, before the popup is closed, and the mother page updated. While those task are performed, the popup is just blank.

What I would like is to display a "please wait..." message on the popup when the callback url is called. One solution is that the popup just display the message and pass an AJAX, but as I don't know the parameters of the callback (that depends on the external application), I would like to avoid this. Is there any way to do it with only one PHP script ?

Comment: Is the callback forward to your site?

Comment: Yes. when the user click on the 'log in with...', it calls a script named 'bzkExternalOAuth.php, where the right API is loaded (Fb, linkedin, google,...). If we use for instance FB, the page is then redirected to FB, and at the end, when the user authorized my site to his FB, it callbacks the same 'bzkExternalOAuth.php'.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the authorization in an iFrame (will require additional work to sync the iframe with the popup to get to the behaviour you have in mind) and design the window as you desire.

<del>You can also just set the title.</del>

Comment: I believe I read somewhere that using an iframe was not a good practice in that case (I can't remember which application's documentation it was)

Comment: I beg your pardon. You cannot change even the title if you don't have control of the "loaded" page (the popped up, which I suggested you add the iframe to.) The callback URL for your auth service controls all of what the user sees after you open that popup with the designated URL. If you don't fancy using the iframe, you're stuck with not being able to do anything about it.

Comment: I can't find the reference to the recommendation of not using an iframe. So I will investigate in this direction again. By additional work, do you mean that I have to set up a periodical observer to check the content of the iframe (if for instance the page is blank, then I "mask" the iframe with some design in the popup containing the iframe) ?

Comment: Nope. Something along the lines of making sure the auth service redirects to a page of yours that contains JS code that treats your parent popup.

Answer (score 0):

As the service will return you to your server - you can try next:
1. Set transfer encoding to chunked.
2. Echo javascript document.write with loader img.
3. Do your processing.
4. Close the window after processing ends.

Comment: Sounds to be what I need. I make a trial ASAP.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks. It works on my dev. server, but still I am having problem to make it on the preprod server, probably due to the configuration of the NGINX reverse proxy. But that is another story ;)

Comment: You can check this as the answer then )

Comment: yes. and now I got it on the preprod server too, adding the _proxy_buffering off;_ in the conf file.